# how to validate email exists in database using luman while create new user?

Tags: php, laravel

how to validate email exists in database using **luman** while create new user?.

my registration controller code

```
$borrower = borrowerRegistration::create($request->all());
          $last_borrower_id=DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
            $store_borrower_array=array();
            $store_borrower_array["borrower_id"]=$last_borrower_id;
        $borrower_result = array('status' => 'true','message' =>'The First step borrower registration successfully.','content'=>array('registration'=>$store_borrower_array));
        return json_encode($borrower_result);
```

please give a valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this way. here User is your Model (I am assuming)

```
if (User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->exists()) {
   // user found
}
```

Replace **Input::get('email')** to your email address from where you are getting and storing it.

Comment: Hey,thanks you so much.actually i written only for webservices and validating in postman .now am getting error - Class App\Http\Controllers\borrower\Input'   not found  . now am using `create($request->all() `for create new user.how can i replace with `Input::get('email')`?.

Comment: you are using $request->all() to get post data so just use $request->email

Comment: Your create($request->all()) will take all post form data and matched with model fields and fillable if it will be there and store it into the data base but you are here want to check that user  email is exists or not. so just after form submission store that mail id into a variable and pass it into the above condition at the place of "Input::get('email').

Comment: Ya fine.you saved my day

Comment: :) My pleasure Ashwin